# iPhone 4s Recover from lost lockscreen password

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 4s.  I've locked it and forgotten the passcode.  I don't have an iTunes backup to restore from.  When I go through the power+home button loop attached to iTunes and then ask it to "restore" it fails saying "This device isn’t eligible for the requested build".  Any idea how a I reset the phone.  I don't actually want to do an iOs update, but iTunes doesn't seem to give me any other option.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.  You can only install a version of iOS that Apple is still signing.  For the 4S, that would be 9.2.1.

Comment: I would tolerate the update if It would let me.  I can't seem to get the update to work since it says "This device isn’t eligible for the requested build".  I've tried updating my version of iTunes but that doesn't fix it.  Do I have to do something special to force it to load the very lates iOS somehow?